# How to call a input file tag in javascript In safari Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

My JavaScript code:

```
$("#formimage").click(function(){
    $("#avatar").click();
});


<input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" style="display: none;" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
```

in this it does not call avatar file tag... and not even giving any error ... in browser console

Comment: This is a security thing; don’t rely on being able to open file upload dialogs automatically in any browser.

Comment: i trying to do on image click, open dialogue box rather than normal file open....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to trigger an input of type file by clicking on something else. The biggest issue that you will run into is that IE will see this as a security concern and might not let you do it (if the input is hidden). To get around this issue, you could "fade" the input behind the image, so that when the user clicks the image, they're actually clicking on the file input.

Your html could look something like this:

```
<div class="hiddenFileInputContainter">
    <img class="fileDownload" src="/images/ico_upload.png">
    <input type="file" name="fileUp" class="hidden" accept="image/*">
</div>
```

Then you would need to set the opacity of the input to zero, in order to let the image behind it be visible, without actually removing the input from the page:

```
input[type='file'].hidden
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=0);
}
```

You would also need to set the dimensions for the image and the container:

```
img.fileDownload
{
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div.hiddenFileInputContainter
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Notice that the input's dimensions are meant to overflow, so that no matter where you click on the container, you will hit the input inside it. The input is meant to be as large as possible and the actual dimensions of the button are set on the container and the image.

Once you've managed to open the dialog, submitting the form would only be a matter of doing this:

```
$("#fileUploadField").on("change", function() {
    $("#formId").submit();
});
```

or else try this to make the file input to look like button:

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/